# Open mapping theorem and direct sum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, bilinear-operator

Let $T$ be an invertible operator on a Banach space $X$. Suppose that $X=M \oplus N$ where $M$ and $N$ are closed  subspaces of $X$,  $T(M)\subseteq M$ and $T(N)\subseteq N$.

In a paper, author claim that by open mapping theorem there is $\beta>0$ such that
$||a||<\beta ||x||$ and $||b||<\beta||x||$ where $x=a\oplus b$.
Proof of it is not clear for me.
I so thankful if give me a reference or idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X=M\oplus N$ where $M$, $N$ are closed subspaces. Define $P:X\to M$ by $Px = a \Leftrightarrow x=a+b$. Then, $P$ is a bounded linear operator with the property $P^2 = P$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\|a\| &=& \|Px\|\leq \|P\|\|x\| \\
\|b\| &=& \|(I-P)x\|\leq \|I-P\|\|x\|
\end{eqnarray}

Let $\beta = \max\{\|P\|,\|I-P\|\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By your proof, we can say that $\beta$ is only dependence on $X, M, N$ and it is not dependence on $T:X\to X$. Is it true?

Comment: @user479859 exactly. You don't need open mapping theorem, either.